# How to minimize column widths and justify text in a table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to figure out a way to present a semi-formalised argument for a paper I'm writing. It seems the best way to do it is to use a table with three columns: the left column with the premiss numbers aligned to the right, a central column with the premisses, and the right column with the premiss labels/inference rules aligned to the right. At the moment my code outputs the following, which is pretty close to what I want:

[image]

There are a couple of changes I want which I can't figure out how to do. First, I would like the text in the middle column to be justified. Second, I would like the left and right columns to be the minimum necessary width.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{baskervillef} %font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % fancy maths latters
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry} %changes margins

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ 
                >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.05\textwidth}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.68\textwidth}
                >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}}
            (1) & If $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ is correct, then: If $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ then $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (Normativity)\\
            (2) & If $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ is correct, then: If $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ then $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (Normativity)\\
            (3) & $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ are correct & (Pluralism)\\
            (4) & If $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ then $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (1,3, MP)\\
            (5) & If $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ then $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (2,3, MP)\\
            (6) & If $O(Bs\varphi)$ and \textit{m} is a reliable method by which \textit{s} can form the belief that $\varphi$, then $\neg O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (\textit{Transmission})\\
            (7) & $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (8) & $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (9) & $O(Bs\Gamma)$ & (\textit{Ex hypothesi})\\
            (10) & \textit{m} is a reliable method by which \textit{s} can form the belief that $\varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (11) & $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (4,7, MP)\\
            (12) & $O(Bs\varphi)$ & (9,11, MP)\\
            (13) & $\neg O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (6,10,12, MP)\\
            (14) & $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (5,8, MP)\\
            (15) & $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ are not correct & (3,13,14, RAA)
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tabularx environment requires at least one `X` column.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXr@{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to be justified, don't use the directive `>{\raggedright}` for the middle column. To minimize the other columns, use the standard `r` specifier. Here is a code, in which I took the liberty to left-align the rightmost column, as it its looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{baskervillef} %font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % fancy maths latters
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry} %changes margins

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}rXl@{}}
            (1) & If $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ is correct, then: If $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ then $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (Normativity)\\
            (2) & If $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ is correct, then: If $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ then $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (Normativity)\\
            (3) & $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ are correct & (Pluralism)\\
            (4) & If $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ then $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (1,3, MP)\\
            (5) & If $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ then $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (2,3, MP)\\
            (6) & If $O(Bs\varphi)$ and \textit{m} is a reliable method by which \textit{s} can form the belief that $\varphi$, then $\neg O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (\textit{Transmission})\\
            (7) & $\Gamma \models_{\mathscr{X}_{1}} \varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (8) & $\Gamma \not\models_{\mathscr{X}_{2}} \varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (9) & $O(Bs\Gamma)$ & (\textit{Ex hypothesi})\\
            (10) & \textit{m} is a reliable method by which \textit{s} can form the belief that $\varphi$ & (Pluralism)\\
            (11) & $O(Bs\Gamma \supset Bs\varphi)$ & (4,7, MP)\\
            (12) & $O(Bs\varphi)$ & (9,11, MP)\\
            (13) & $\neg O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (6,10,12, MP)\\
            (14) & $O\neg(Fs\varphi m)$ & (5,8, MP)\\
            (15) & $\mathscr{X}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{X}_{2}$ are not correct & (3,13,14, RAA)
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change  the `\begin{tabularx}` as follows:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rXr}
```

you get:

1. first column right aligned (`r`), which width is computed by LaTeX to be the minimum required
2. center column justified (`X`), with auto linebreak
3. third column right aligned (`r`), which width is computed by LaTeX to be the minimum required

You can control the width of the table with the second parameter given to the environment `{\textwidth}`, which you can multiply by a scaling factor; for example `{0.75\textwidth}`.

You may see "extra space" between columns because you forced the table to be as large as `\textwidth`.

Also, take into consideration the fact that columns are separated by some horizontal space.
If you want to remove it, simply do

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r@{}X@{}r}
```

But the result can be ugly. Some space between columns is nicer.
In any case, you can put inside `@{}` the length you prefer, like, for example

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r@{\,}X@{\,}r}
```